# How to make a pie with different levels of the scheme (cytoscape.js)?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Now it looks like this (now - first):

[image]

A need that would be so (result - second):

[image]

**Please help to make the second one (beautiful) version**

Answer (score 1):

Node positioning is up to your choice of layout and the options you specify.

See

- http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions

CoSE, CoSE-Bilkent, Cola, and Spread are examples of force-directed/physics layouts, which is what you are looking for.  You will have to try different layout and different options for each layout to see what works best with your data.  CoSE-Bilkent is a good one to try first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was just with him, and using the first version. Code: ... layout: { name: 'cose-bilkent',
    animate: false,
    nodeRepulsion: 1100000,
    idealEdgeLength: 1100,
    edgeElasticity: 1,

    nestingFactor: 0.1,

    gravityCompound: .1,

    padding: 5,
    randomize: false,
    gravity: .1,
    numIter: 2510,
    fit:true }

Comment: but I can not get at the elements of 2 levels that have their elements (Level 3) were built on a circle around a parent (level 2).

Comment: You have to experiment yourself.  It's different for different data.  Physics layouts do not always create equilateral geometric shapes -- they're force-directed simulations.  If you want strict geometries according to whatever criteria you have, you'll have to write your own layout or have a person manually curate your position data.